# Type-based database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, join

I want to rate (Very Good, Good, Medium, Bad...) 2 objects: Student and Teacher. Which design solution is better?

**Solution 1:**

> Students(StudentID, Rating,...)
>
> -----------------1--------Good-----
>
> -----------------2--------Bad-----
>
> -----------------3-----Very Good-----
>
> ---
>
> Teachers(TeacherID, Rating,...)
>
> -----------------1-----Very Good-----
>
> -----------------2--------Bad-----
>
> -----------------3--------Bad-----

**Solution 2:**

> Students(StudentID, RatingTypeID,...)
>
> -----------------1----------------2----------
>
> -----------------2----------------1----------
>
> -----------------3----------------3----------
>
> ---
>
> Teachers(TeacherID, RatingTypeID,...)
>
> -----------------1----------------1----------
>
> -----------------2----------------1----------
>
> -----------------3----------------3----------
>
> ---
>
> RatingType(RatingID, RatingDescription,...)
>
> -----------------1-------------Very Good---------
>
> -----------------2---------------Good--------------
>
> -----------------3----------------Bad---------------
>
> ---

If both of them are not good enough, can you give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 2 is the best from those two, but if You want to have multiple votes in the course of your application's life, you should have a table where you identify what is the subject of the vote, and another where you store the votes:

```
Student:
   id
   name
   class
   ...

Teacher:
   id
   name
   subject
   ...

voterType
   id 
   description (student or teacher)

contest:
   id
   description (ex: 1st Semester 2013)

contestVotes:
   id
   contestId
   voterType (Teacher or Student)
   voterId
   ratingTypeId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question about your design: `contestVotes` table. If I want to fetch more information about voter, I have to check `voterType` (Teacher or Student) and join to corresponding table (Teacher or Student)? How can I do that using MySQL?

Comment: If you want to select directly where voterType = student, you can inner join with student and get from there. If you want to get information about both students and teachers, you can do the inner join ON contestVotes..voterID = student.id AND contestVotes.voterType = 1(student), same for teachers. Did that answer your question? or did i miss what you were trying to ask?

Comment: I mean I want to get information about voter of `contestVotes.id = 1` (for example). Of course, I don't know which type of voter, I just know one thing of input is `contestVote ID`.

Comment: That depends on what information you want to have in your students/teachers. Usually what you want to know in a table like contestVotes is a way to know how many teachers/students voted and on what. If you want to get information from the different tables student and teacher at the same time, you would have to create a way of outputing both information that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Between the two suggested solutions, I would definitely choose the second one, for the following reasons:

- Storing a `Rating` as a number can come handy in cases where ordering or aggregates are involved, in which cases a string is pretty much useless.
- Making the `Rating` column a Foreign Key to the `RatingType.RatingID` enforces a constraint, that a `Rating` can only have values from a very specific set, with very specific meaning. Plus, you could potentially add extra columns to the `RatingType` table in the future, adding value to your ratings.

As for an improvement suggestion, since you asked, consider implementing this using [IS-A relations](http://www.geomagas.gr/index.php/is-a-relations-in-relational-databases/). A teacher, as well as a student, are apparently both `Persons` and have common attributes to an extent. I would create a `Person` superclass table containing the common attributes (i.e. first name, last name, address, phone etc) and then make the primary keys of `students` and `teachers` also foreign keys to `Persons`.

Notice that, a rating is a common attribute too. So it's only natural to appear in the `Persons` table. Unless of course there are different types of ratings for teachers and students, in which case you would have to implement two different `RatingType` tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question about performance: if I choose the `solution 2`, I have to use `join` (`RatingType` & `Teachers` or `RatingType` & `Students`) to get all information, so if `RatingType` table contains very few rows, `Students` and `Teachers` tables are huge, the performance in cost term when using `join` operation is expensive?

Comment: @JackCood In that case, you will have to perform a `union` between `student` and `teacher` first, _then_ join the result with `RatingType`. That's why I proposed the IS-A approach, where you would have to join only `person` with `RatingType` most of the time. Granted, `person` is even bigger, but using the right `index`es performance should be the least of your problems.